# How to customize twitter widget style?

Tags: css, twitter

I just implemented the lists widget on my site: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

I just want to override the background-color from white to transparent. Since it is a embedded widget I cannot edit it directly. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

You can change the Chrome of the widget, to hide the header/footer/border or background.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="<YOUR ID>" data-theme="dark" data-link-color="#000" data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders transparent"  data-related="twitterapi,twitter" data-aria-polite="assertive" width="300" height="300" lang="EN">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! It seems they just added that in their docs :)

Comment: add "noscrollbar" to remove the scrollbar as well.

Comment: Scroll down to the 'Client Side Options' section.

Comment: do you know how to hide the images (avatars) ? and change the styles of the other elements ?

Comment: Does this work for single embedded tweets? I can't seem to get data-chrome attribute properties to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74012606/7186739

Answer (score 5):

Create a widget from twitter>settings>widgets.

Copy-paste the code provided.

```
<a
class="twitter-timeline"
href="https://twitter.com/YourNickname"
data-widget-id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" <!--you will haveyour own number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375116/what-is-data-widget-id-in-twitter-api-how-i-can-get-the-data-widget-id-->
data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders noscrollbar transparent" <!--tweak these for the looks-->
data-tweet-limit="5"
data-link-color="#FFFFFF"
data-border-color="#FFFFFF"
lang="EN" data-theme="light" <!--light or dark-->
height="447"
width="255"
data-screen-name="yourName"
data-show-replies="false"
data-aria-polite="assertive">

Tweets by @YourName

</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

For the answer i used the work from http://tweetsdecoder.net/.
His snippet apparently doesn't work because of the script.

Cheers!

Edited:There was my nickname there

Comment: +1 Very Useful when trying to customize the twitter widget according to fit the website style.

Comment: @Neurone00 Please Make Sure You Update Your Widget Id.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using something like the following (can't really find much reference for this now, but it's still working) (change `<YOUR_TWIITER_NAME>` with yours):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 300,
  height: 288,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: 'transparent',
      color: '#2c458f'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: 'transparent',
      color: '#525252',
      links: '#ad1111'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('<YOUR_TWIITER_NAME>').start();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But It didn't work too. Maybe the website where you have used can help me :)

Comment: OP: You're not changing the background color, therefore this is not exactly an "answer".

Comment: @ManojKumar, edited. I've just provided it as a boilerplate, so you can make your own customization, since I don't know the colors you need or parts that need to be transparent.

Comment: I think he just wants the tweets part to be transparent, not sure though.

Comment: this is actually deprecated now and wont work since the twitter api v1 is no longer supported :/

Answer (score 1):

If you need further customisations, try using [TwitterPostFetcher](https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher) by Jason Mayes. It allows for complete styling of timeline tweets - much more than the default style parameters that the stock twitter widgets provide.

Answer (score 0):

At  the moment this is what twitter rendered in your web page.
[image: Tweets Widgets Decoded]

Since you know all the id and class attributes you can then control it with css or JavaScript 
this Link http://tweetsdecoder.net may also be useful on how to customize twitter widgets.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background of `a.twitter-timeline add data-chrome="transparent"` and place the anchor within an element with a CSS background-color