# Change user timeline summary text

Tags: twitter, header, widget, customization, tweets

I'm using the Twitter User Timeline widget from [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/user). I want to change the summary that reads "Tweets" in the header, to say "News". How do I do that?

[image: Twitter User Timeline widget]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method #1**

Quite untechnical: Why not simply put your "sign" above the header? You know where the widget will be positioned, so in that same container go ahead and create a small `div` to put your topic there that covers the header saying *Tweets*.

**Method #2**

You can use the styling options as seen in [Embedded Timeline Parameter Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/parameters) to hide the header:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/fabric" data-widget-id="600720083413962752" data-chrome="noheader">Tweets von @fabric </a>
```

You can then add your custom header above the widget.

Obvious downside of this: you lose the follow button, which however you could easily include above the timeline widget by using the [Follow Button widget](https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button).

**Other**

If none of the above is appealing to you, you can try what others tried and fiddle with the DOM after the widget is loaded: [Styling the new twitter widget (embedded timeline)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15533967/155668)