# What is data-widget-id in twitter api ? How i can get the data-widget-id?

Tags: twitter

I have some problems with previous version of the twitter api and I want to move to latest version.  I see some information here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines.

What is `data-widget-id` here.  I want to show some specified people tweets in my website.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question is already answered on the Twitter Developers page.

> To create a timeline you must be signed in to twitter.com and visit the widgets section of your settings page. From this page you can see a list of the timelines you've configured and create new timelines.

1. Sign in on twitter.com
2. [Create a new widget](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new)
3. The widget-id is provided by Twitter (you will be redirected to https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ - the xxx is your widget-id)

Comment: But when  i use that i can able to see only my tweets.How i can see others tweets

Comment: You can set any Twitter account as the widget's source in the settings not only your own. But it's not a dynamic solution, you're right.

Comment: what is data-widget-id here

Comment: A data-widget-id is simply the identifier of a widget. It tells Twitter which widget data to load.

Answer (score 11):

Found the solution.

You can override the `data-widget-id` parameter in the widget by additionally setting the `data-screen-name` parameter inside the `a` tag of the widget. Like this:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/<%= escape_javascript(@site.twitter_username) %>" data-widget-id="363460440807833600" data-screen-name="garzagabriel"></a>
```

**NOTE**: You still need to include the `data-widget-id` parameter. So generate the widget first by going to https://twitter.com/settings/widgets, and then add the `data-screen-name` parameter to the `a` tag in the embed code (like shown above)

Here is the documentation for this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#timeline-selection

Best!

Comment: Great stuff, not really the answer, but helped my issue!