# How to remove tweet photos from twitter widget?

Tags: image, twitter, widget

to display and style my tweets on my website I use somethiong like this code:

```
<a
class="twitter-timeline"
href="https://twitter.com/YourNickname"
data-widget-id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" <!--you will haveyour own number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375116/what-is-data-widget-id-in-twitter-api-how-i-can-get-the-data-widget-id-->
data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders noscrollbar transparent" <!--tweak these for the looks-->
data-tweet-limit="5"
data-link-color="#FFFFFF"
data-border-color="#FFFFFF"
lang="EN" data-theme="light" <!--light or dark-->
height="447"
width="255"
data-screen-name="yourName"
data-show-replies="false"
data-aria-polite="assertive">

Tweets by @YourName

</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

I'm looking for a way to remove images in case they are twitted.

Looking for a solution I've found this:
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/19073

They suggest to add a line

```
data-src-2x="false"
```

to my code.
This solution, sadly, doesn't seem to work for me.

If any of you have solved this problem, a hint would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following answer is no longer relevant due to recent changes by twitter!**

<strike>In the configuration options when creating the widget there is a checkbox labeled 'auto expand photos'.  Uncheck this, but be aware it takes</strike>

Comment: Twitter has removed the  'auto expand photos' checkbox: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new