# How to style Twitter widget using my own CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter

I have my own design for a Twitter feed and I want to style the default feed using my own design. Is there a way to do that?

The issue is that you can't use the CSS selectors because it appears only after the loading the page.

Please check this pic to give you more idea about what I need

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/twitter-widget.jpg]

Thanks,

Comment: "How to style a twitter widget?"- By using `CSS`. "Is there a way to do that?"- Yes, by making use of CSS selectors.

Comment: You can't use the CSS selectors to style the feed because it appears only after loading the page.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter if it appears after loading the page. If your CSS is authored to target the content appropriately and the content is loaded onto your page (ie, not in an iframe, which is someone else's page), your styles will apply whenever it loads.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that Twitter does occasionally delete account and/or block API access if you style Twitter content in a way they don't like. Yeah, I know that sounds crazy, but here are Twitter's "display requirements": https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize twitter widget style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303710/how-to-customize-twitter-widget-style)

Comment: Working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74012606/7186739

Answer (score 2):

Well, You can customize Your twitter widget by doing something like this:

Default Code

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="Pagelink" data-widget-id="Page ID">Tweets by @Test</a>
```

To remove Header footer, Just add data-chrome="nofooter transparent noheader transparent" and it will look something like this:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="Pagelink" data-widget-id="Page ID" data-chrome="nofooter transparent noheader transparent">Tweets by @Test</a>
```

For more customization like link color, Borders etc refer to this article. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#customization

I hope this helps :)

Comment: You only need one transparent

Answer (score 1):

1# Getting a fully customisable timeline like suggested earlier (by using the API), would require that you fetch the timeline as a json file (https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json) and manually loop them in your display. More details here https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline

2# This is as close as I could come with your design @shadeed9. Most of the restrictions are here https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/display-requirements
[image: final_result_tweetdesign]

3# This JS snippet will let you add custom CSS styles to the Twitter embed widget: https://github.com/kevinburke/customize-twitter-1.1 by Kevin Burke

If this solves your question, kindly **accept** it!

Answer (score 0):

If by twitter widget you mean the embedded timelines, then see the "client side options" section of the docs https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines for options that you can set.

If you want totally customised output using CSS, then you'll need to write your own solution using the API to spit out content that can be styled.

Comment: Yes, I want totally customized output. Could you please explain more about using the API? What I should do?

Comment: The issue with the API is it does not give you the full text of most tweets unfortunately. Otherwise, it's a great option.