# Customizing a Twitter Tweet on Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

What I'm trying to accomplish:
[image]

When I inspect the element and get the appropriate classes and then apply the styles, nothing seems to happen.  Why is this?  How can I go about changing the styles of my tweet for my webpage?

```css
.Tweet-header.u-cf{
  display:none !important;
  
}
div#twitter-widget-0 {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="ro" dir="ltr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ut porttitor elit. Nulla mattis sem et ullamcorper pretium. Nunc malesu</p>&mdash; Jason (@jasontestsus) <a href="https://twitter.com/jasontestsus/status/699685458146623489">February 16, 2016</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/4ewm1hjd/

Comment: Is the fiddle working? I'm not clear on what the exact issue is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style Twitter widget using my own CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663924/how-to-style-twitter-widget-using-my-own-css)

Comment: The fiddle is working on my end, is the twitter not working on yours?  When I tried to embed it on stack, it didn't display the twitter, but my URL fiddle does.

Comment: @brod I took a look at that link, doesn't solve my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Twitter [widget events](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events) to detect when the tweet has been loaded, then update the CSS as needed:

```
$(function() {
  twttr.events.bind('loaded', function(event) {
    var $iframe = $(frames['twitter-widget-0']);
    $('#twitter-widget-0', $iframe.contents()).css({
      'background-color': 'orange'
    });
    $('.Tweet-header.u-cf', $iframe.contents()).css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
  });  
});
```

The reason your CSS isn't applied to the tweet widget is that the widget is in an `iframe` and, as far as I know, an `iframe` will ignore CSS rules in its parent `document` unless the `iframe` and the parent `document` are in the same domain.