# How to customize twitter widget for html

Tags: html, twitter

I just implemented the lists widget on my site ([embedded-timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines)).

I just want to override letters color from black to any other color.

Since it is an embedded widget I cannot edit it directly. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this question: [How to customize twitter widget style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303710/how-to-customize-twitter-widget-style)

It's like the exact same thing as yours.

Anyway, I found this answer on the link I gave you. Dunno if it might help...(It might not, go check out the link)

You can change the Chrome of the widget, to hide the header/footer/border or background.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-  widget-id="<YOUR ID>" data-theme="dark" data-link-color="#000" data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders transparent"  data-related="twitterapi,twitter" data-aria-polite="assertive" width="300" height="300" lang="EN">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>
```

Comment: I want to change the color and font of texts, not the background, Can you help me

Comment: did you check out the link I gave you?

Comment: I figured using those tags you could change the font...Anyway I'm sorry that's all I can do

Comment: Is there any option to change the font?

Comment: why don't you check out the place you downloaded it from, it should have developer information