# How do I embed recent tweets from a profile onto my website

Tags: html, css, twitter, web, embed

I've tried to embed a profile timeline with the widget Twitter provide but it doesn't let you customize it and its way too big and shows too many tweets for my liking.

Just wanted to know if there was any other way to do it? from scratch or to customize the widget Twitter provide??

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303710/how-to-customize-twitter-widget-style. Also note the second answer there: if you have access to the account you want to embed the timeline of, you can customize an embed in the account's settings.